# Android JSON for statement JAVA

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

The output keeps repeating the name for each property. Only need to see the name once, and then prop_name and address can print out for each occassion under the single name. The JSON looks like:

```
 [{"pmid":"2","name":"CARLYLE MANAGEMENT","result":"1","properties":[{"prop_id":"32","prop_name":"Bonneville Tower","address":"25801 Lakeshore","city":"Euclid","state":"OH","zip":"44132","lat":"41.6223","long":"-81.5034"}]},
 {"pmid":"1","name":"COMMERCIAL ONE REALTY","result":"18","properties":[{"prop_id":"3","prop_name":"Autumn Chase Apartments","address":"146 Grand Circuit Blvd.","city":"Delaware","state":"OH","zip":"43015","lat":"40.3105","long":"-83.1138"},
{"prop_id":"6","prop_name":"Barrington Club Apartments","address":"4600 Barrington Club","city":"Columbus","state":"OH","zip":"43220","lat":"40.0536","long":"-83.0448"},{"prop_id":"17","prop_name":"Battleship Building Condominium","address":"444 North Front St.","city":"Columbus","state":"OH","zip":"43215","lat":"39.9712","long":"-83.0042"}]
```

The code is currently:

```
  String pmid = mJsonObject.getString("pmid");
                String name = mJsonObject.getString("name");
                String result = mJsonObject.getString("result");

                    JSONArray mJsonArrayProperty = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");
                    int innerLength = mJsonArrayProperty.length();
                    for (int k = 0; k < innerLength; k++) {
              //  JSONArray mJsonArrayProperty = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");
              //  for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArrayProperty.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject mJsonObjectProperty = mJsonArrayProperty.getJSONObject(k);

                    String prop_id = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("prop_id");
                    String prop_name = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("prop_name");
                    String address = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("address");
                    String city = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("city");
                    String state = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("state");
                    String zip = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("zip");
                    String lat = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("lat");
                    String lon = mJsonObjectProperty.getString("long");

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact

                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, prop_name);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE, address);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }

            } }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The output gives me the prop_name and address but it also says the name over and over each time. The goal is to see the name once and then the multiple properties under it. How can this be accomplished with a for or if statement, or any other way.

Comment: Aren't you using `CustomAdapter` ???

Comment: is your `mJsonObject` is an array ??

Comment: Yes BBDev it is an array

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing the algo, How you can do it...

- First you have to get the `JSONObject` in which you have the `jsondata`.
- From that `JSONObject` you should get `JSONArray` because the whole `jsondata` you have is an array.
- Now from that `JSONArray` you should get the string `pmid`, name etc..
- Now again you have to get `JSONArray` because **`properties`** is `JSONArray` now you can iterate it.

And for doing this you should have use two for loop or any iteration method you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try Out this...

    JSONArray one=new JSONArray(json);
      for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject=one.getJSONObject(i);
        String pmid=jsonObject.getString("pmid");
        String name=jsonObject.getString("name");
        String result=jsonObject.getString("result");
        JSONArray properties=jsonObject.getJSONArray("properties");
        for (int j = 0; j < properties.length(); j++)
        {
            JSONObject js=properties.getJSONObject(j);
            String prop_id=js.getString("prop_id");
            String prop_name=js.getString("prop_name");
            String address=js.getString("address");
            String city=js.getString("city");
            String state=js.getString("state");
            String zip=js.getString("zip");
            String lat=js.getString("lat");
            String Long=js.getString("long");
        }
    }
```

Comment: this still displayed name again each time properties was listed